# Adding a page to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

Trying to programmatically add a fragment page to my ViewPager, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged!
Expected adapter item count: 3, found: 2
Pager id: com.my.app:id/view_pager
Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
Problematic adapter: class com.my.app.ui.BaseFragmentPagerAdapter
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1000)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
            at ...
```

I'm simply calling these few lines on my `FragmentPagerAdapter` implementation:

```
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(), "FIRST");
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(), "SECOND");
pager.setAdapter(adapter);

//later... (on click of a button)
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(), "THIRD");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It actually adds the third page, but when I try to swipe there, it fails with the above mentioned exception. Until today I thought I had a pretty complete understanding of how adapters work. Now I can't figure out what's wrong.

From debugging, it seems that all the time `adapter.getCount()` correctly returns 3 (after adding the third page), but when I'm there to the third page it eventually returns 2 and breaks, as if someone called `destroyItem()` on it, but that's not me.

Here's my simple class:

```
public class BaseFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private SparseArray<Fragment> mFragments;
    private ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitles;

    public BaseFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        this.mFragments = new SparseArray<>();
        this.mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment f, String title) {
        this.mFragments.append(mFragments.size() , f);
        this.mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.mFragments == null ? null : this.mFragments.get(position) ;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return this.mFragments.indexOfValue((Fragment) object);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        this.mFragments.remove(position);
        this.mFragmentTitles.remove(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentTitles.size();
    }

}
```

Note that nothing changes if I use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` rather than `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this myself since I found the answer while writing the question (as often). I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it worked.

Basically, when going to page 3, since it's not directly swipable-to, the adapter will call `destroyItem()` on page 1. Shouldn't `FragmentPagerAdapter` hold all items in memory without destroying them?

Well, I do hold fragments in memory through the `mFragments` fields. The call to `destroyItem()` destroys the associated view of the fragment, but should not destroy the fragment itself (I might be slightly wrong here, but you get the point).

So it's up to you (me) to keep the fragments in memory, and **not** invalidating them on `destroyItem()`. Specifically, I had to remove these two lines:

```
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        //removed: this.mFragments.remove(position);
        //removed: this.mFragmentTitles.remove(position);
    }
```

This way `getCount()` keeps returning correctly 3, and when you are back to page 1, the adapter can get its fragment through `getItem()`.

### Edit

After dealing with it for a day, I can say that, at a first glance, having a `FragmentPagerAdapter` that does not hold fragments in memory makes no sense to me.

It is documented that it should be used just for a few static fragments. `ViewPager`, by default, holds the current item, the one before and the one after, but you can tune this setting through `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`.

If you destroy them during `destroyItem()`, things get bad. It will be easy to reinstantiate them through some logic in `getItem()`, but it is quite hard to save their instance state. For instance, `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate)` is not called after `destroyItem()`.

If your fragments are many and you want to accept the possibility that one of more get destroyed, you just switch to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, but that's another story: it automatically calls `onSaveInstanceState` and lets you retain what you need to retain.

Using `FragmentPagerAdapter`, thus renouncing on the state-saving features of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, makes no sense if you don't retain. I mean, either you retain the instances, or you save their state (as suggested in the comments). For the latter, though, I would go for `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that makes it easy.

(*Note: I'm not talking about retaining instances when the activity gets destroyed, but rather when a page of the ViewPager goes through `destroyItem` and the associated fragment goes through `onDestroyView()`*).

Comment: Adapter should not hold fragments in memory. Fragments are destroyed when system decides so, but when being recreated you receive bundle with saved state so you can restore your data.

Comment: @wasyl note that this is a 3 item adapter, no more. Apart from that, how would you modify my adapter? If I don't remove these two lines, getCount() returns 2 and the view pager complains because it expects 3.